# Issue installing mongoDB version 3.1.9 on solaris 10

Tags: mongodb, database

I was trying to install mongoDB version 3.1.9 on solaris 10 .
getting the below error while installation

**ld.so.1: mongo: fatal: relocation error: file mongo: symbol strnlen: referenced symbol not found
Killed**

I have never worked with mongoDB before not sure if I am installing properly.

Comment: uname -a
SunOS  5.10 Generic_150401-38 i86pc i386 i86pc

Comment: ./mongod
ld.so.1: mongod: fatal: libsocket.so.1: version 'SUNW_1.7' not found (required by file mongod)
ld.so.1: mongod: fatal: libsocket.so.1: open failed: No such file or directory
Killed

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately MONGODB do not support Solaris 10 at this time. You'll need to upgrade to Solaris 11 if you'd like to use newer versions of MongoDB.

Comment: thanks waleed, can U tell me when you are referring to "newer versions" which all versions do that include, I mean 3.0.X or the versions before that too.

Comment: I have read the jira https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-23565 but not sure which latest release i can install on solaris 10

Comment: https://www.opencsw.org/get-it/packages/ on opencsw i have checked the package present is 2.0.4, So is it like I can install only till version 2.0.4 on solaris 10

Comment: Current latest MonoDb version is 3.2 and it is stable release u can also give this a try... While 3.3.x releases are available, these versions of MongoDB are for testing purposes only and not for production use.

Answer (score 0):

./mongod ld.so.1: mongod: fatal: libsocket.so.1: version 'SUNW_1.7' not found (required by file mongod) ld.so.1: mongod: fatal: libsocket.so.1: open failed: No such file or directory Killed @mahi_walia

This shows that some binary and libs files required by MongoDB are missing for successful installation.

If you apply the Solaris patch cluster that will upgrade all the necessary binaries and libs, this should resolve your issue.

Here you can download Recommended patch cluster for Solaris.
https://blogs.oracle.com/patch/entry/a_solaris_recommended_patchset_to